# Image uploading to directory while saving path in mySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, image

So, I have an assignment in which i need to let users report bugs in games directly to the developers using a form on their site. On this form there needs to be various info, inlcuding the possibility of uploding a photo of the error you have encountered. I'm having trouble with this feature, so if someone would take some time to look over my code i would be very gratefull :)

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Raporter Bugs</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bug_report_table_div">
<div id="overskrift_bug">Raporter Feil</div>
<div id="bug_report_table">

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
<td>Navn på spill</td>
<td><select name="spill">
<option value="Synapsis">Synapsis</option>
<option value="Profit">Profit</option>
<option value="Blobb">Blobb</option>
</select></td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Når fant feilen sted?  </td>
<td><input type="text" name="tidspunkt"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Feil funnet av</td>
<td><input type="text" name="rapportør" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Picture of the bug</td>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
<input type="file" name="photo"> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Beskriv problemet</td>
<td><textarea rows="5" cols="35" name="beskrivelse"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><div id="submit_button_bugs"><input type="submit"><div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if( !session_id() ) session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","epicsoft");
$host="127.0.0.1"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="epicsoft"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="bugs"; // Table name 


// Check connection
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select database");

//variables
$spill = $_POST['spill']; 
$tidspunkt = $_POST['tidspunkt'];
$rapportør = $_POST['rapportør'];
$pic = ($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$beskrivelse = $_POST['beskrivelse'];

$target ="images";
$target = $target.basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
?>
<html>
<div id="navigation_buttons">
<form action="user_login.php" method="post">
<table><tr>
<br><br><br>
<td>Click here to go to login screen</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="register" value="Continue"></td>
</tr></form>
<form action="user_registration.php" method="post">
<tr>
<br><br><br>
<td>Click here to return to the registration page</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="register" value="Back"></td>
</tr></table>
</div>
```

The error message i get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: photo in C:\xampp\htdocs\insert.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: photo in C:\xampp\htdocs\insert.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined index: photo in C:\xampp\htdocs\insert.php on line 28
```

Thanks, please help

Answer (score 0):

In your form u need to include enctype in order to upload files to system

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

So in php side `$_FILES` will provide you all info about the file being uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<form action="user_registration.php" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="user_registration.php" method="post"  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```